# Applying conditional transformations based on commonalities between variables names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Due to a coding error in some online survey collection software I have some variables in a dataset where 0 could be either 'no change' or simply NA. There is no way to disambiguate them from the source, but it is possible based on values of upstream variables: if a person has checked one variable upstream and then indicated no change then the value in the target is a legitimate 'no change', whereas if they have not checked the upstream variable and the value of the target is 0 then the value in the target should be NA.

I could do all this manually but there are a LOT of these target and upstream variables, so I would rather do it with some kind of apply or loop function.

The upstream and target variables have a string that indicates they are linked. Here is some toy data to illustrate. The `symptom_foo` variables are the upstream variables, indicating whether the respondent has tried to treat the symptom in question with the drug in question. The `sym_foo_change` variables indicate whether the symptom in question is better, worse or no change after using the drug.

```
df <- data.frame(pID = factor(1:4),
                 symptom_dep = factor(c("checked", "unchecked", "checked", "checked")),
                 symptom_anx = factor(c("unchecked", "unchecked", "checked", "checked")),
                 sym_dep_change = factor(c("noChangeOrNA", "noChangeOrNA", "better", "worse")),
                 sym_anx_change = factor(c("noChangeOrNA", "noChangeOrNA", "worse", "noChangeOrNA")))


df

#   pID symptom_dep symptom_anx sym_dep_change sym_anx_change
# 1   1     checked   unchecked   noChangeOrNA   noChangeOrNA
# 2   2   unchecked   unchecked   noChangeOrNA   noChangeOrNA
# 3   3     checked     checked         better          worse
# 4   4     checked     checked          worse   noChangeOrNA
```

Rather than use numerical variables as he target I have used factors, with 'noChangeOrNA' representing the values that are ambiguous. I need a sub-routine that can get the following out put. `symptom_dep` is the upstream variable for the target `sym_dep_change` and `symtom_anx` the upstream for `sym_anx_change`. When `symptom_dep = "checked"` and `sym_dep_change = "noChangeOrNA` I need `sym_dep_change` to become 'noChange' and when `symptom_dep = "Unchecked"` and `sym_dep_change = "noChangeOrNA` I need `sym_dep_change` to become `NA` and similar for the `anx` variables.

After the function is applied it should look something like this

```
#   pID symptom_dep symptom_anx sym_dep_change sym_anx_change
# 1   1     checked   unchecked       noChange           <NA>
# 2   2   unchecked   unchecked           <NA>           <NA>
# 3   3     checked     checked         better          worse
# 4   4     checked     checked          worse       noChange
```

As I said I can do this manually in the toy example with the following code

```
df %>%
  mutate(sym_dep_change = case_when(symptom_dep == "checked" & sym_dep_change == "noChangeOrNA" ~ "noChange",
                                    symptom_dep == "unchecked" & sym_dep_change == "noChangeOrNA" ~ NA_character_,
                                    TRUE ~ sym_dep_change),
         sym_anx_change = case_when(symptom_anx == "checked" & sym_anx_change == "noChangeOrNA" ~ "noChange",
                                    symptom_anx == "unchecked" & sym_anx_change == "noChangeOrNA" ~ NA_character_,
                                    TRUE ~ sym_anx_change))
```

...but there are scores of these pairs of variables so I need a process whereby the procedure above is performed automatically based on the common `foo` contained in the name of each pair. At present I don't really know where to start.

A tidyverse solution would be great but anything that gets it done will do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this easier if you pivot the data to long format.  As a first step, rename some of the variables so the pattern is consistent (i.e. if you have a variable called `symptom_dep` then it's easier to work with its corresponding variable if it's called `change_dep` than if it's called `sym_dep_change`). Once renamed, it's a simple matter of pivoting then using `ifelse()` to replace the desired values to `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  rename_with(~sub("sym_(.*)_(change)", "\\2_\\1", .x), ends_with("change")) |>
  pivot_longer(-pID, names_to = c(".value", "symptom_name"), names_sep = "_", ) |>
  mutate(change = if_else(symptom == "unchecked", NA, change))

# A tibble: 8 × 4
  pID   symptom_name symptom   change      
  <fct> <chr>        <fct>     <fct>       
1 1     dep          checked   noChangeOrNA
2 1     anx          unchecked NA          
3 2     dep          unchecked NA          
4 2     anx          unchecked NA          
5 3     dep          checked   better      
6 3     anx          checked   worse       
7 4     dep          checked   worse       
8 4     anx          checked   noChangeOrNA
```

You will find it easier to work with the data if it's kept in this format but if you must pivot it back, you can use

```
... |>
 pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = c(symptom, change))

# A tibble: 4 × 5
  pID   symptom_dep symptom_anx change_dep   change_anx  
  <fct> <fct>       <fct>       <fct>        <fct>       
1 1     checked     unchecked   noChangeOrNA NA          
2 2     unchecked   unchecked   NA           NA          
3 3     checked     checked     better       worse       
4 4     checked     checked     worse        noChangeOrNA
```

Comment: Thank you @Richie Sacramento. I'd like to keep it long for sure but I'm creating a master dataset (for other people to use as well as me) and the columns I'm talking about are 80 of about 800, so it's strictly one row per respondent atm. Thanks again